# How can I make a navigation bar fill up the whole width of the screen?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I've been trying to make a navbar, but even when I set the width to 100%, it doesn't take up the width. I attached my code here.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html" id="nav">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="Generator.html" id="nav">Generator</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html" id="nav">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html" id="nav">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the default margin on the body or add `left:0` to your `ul` rules:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
body {margin:0;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html" id="nav">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="Generator.html" id="nav">Generator</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html" id="nav">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html" id="nav">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}


ul{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background-color: #003580;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}
ul li{
  background-color: #dddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0 2px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
.nav{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Barra de navegación</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylos.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="nav">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Generator.html" class="nav">Generator</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html" class="nav">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html" class="nav">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).